# How to get average of 4 colors in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rmagick

I'm getting 4 colors off an image using RMagick using this code:

```
color1 = img.pixel_color(1,1)
color2 = img.pixel_color(50,1)
color3 = img.pixel_color(1,50)
color4 = img.pixel_color(50,50)
```

**How can I compute the average of these 4 colors?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
colors = [color1, color2, color3, color4]
avg = Pixel.new colors.collect(&:red).inject(:+)/colors.size,
  colors.collect(&:green).inject(:+)/colors.size,
  colors.collect(&:blue).inject(:+)/colors.size
```

Comment: HSV or HSL would probably be a better coordinate system than RGB for this sort of thing.